# Web scraping with Python, but values are empty

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'd like to grab values from this site: http://cdn.ime-co.ir/ with **BeautifulSoup** , but values are empty when I try to import tables. I think disabled with javascrip or anything that I don't know.
Please help me to export values to csv or txt format.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://cdn.ime-co.ir/').read())
print soup
```

Comment: >>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://cdn.ime-co.ir/').read())
>>> print soup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup doesn't support Javascript. If you just need to parse it once you can obviously save the source to a file and parse from there. If you need to grab the site more than once you could look at using Webkit ([here's an example using PyQT4 with Webkit](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/)) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to generate source that you can parse in Python.